# PHP DOM loadHTML() method unusual warning

Tags: php, dom, webserver

I had the following code which works fine on my localhost:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($p_result);

$form = $document->getElementsByTagName('form')->item(0);

// Code continues using the $form variable
```

After same code get updated on outside server, `loadHTML()` failed and issued this warning.

```
Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in path/name/to/script.php
```

Returned NULL as well instead of object so code pretty soon gets to the fatal error.

Note that the contents of `$p_result` is absolutely the same on outside server and on my localhost.

But why does it displays that kind of warning and why does it not work?

Doesn't it `loadHTML()` expects argument 1 to be a string in the first place?

Why does it say that this method `expects parameter 1 to be a valid path`?

Just to make it clear I'm not calling `loadHTMLFile()`, I'm calling `loadHTML()`.

Thanks.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, I have been working on it for 2 days, no breakthrough yet. It may be related this this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69679

Comment: It depends on php version, that's why it does not work on remote server. According to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69679 try to remove null bytes from your HTML.

Comment: @pamelus how can I do that the efficent way?

Comment: str_replace("\0", '', $htmlContent) should do the job

Comment: @pamelus: Could you please post your comments as an answer? It really solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're affected by [one of PHP bugs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69679). The issue was present only in PHP 5.6.8 and 5.6.9. Most likely you have affected PHP version on the server, and bug-free version on your localhost.

The bug itself forbids all null characters in HTML document you're loading, so as a workaround you may try to remove those (actually not needed) characters before further parsing.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$p_result_without_null_chars = str_replace("\0", '', $p_result)
$document->loadHTML($p_result_without_null_chars);
```

Comment: Yeas that was exactly it and it and because of that bug one of my freelance job failed. Can't believe they let something like this in production.