# XPath query returns false even when nodes exist

Tags: php, xpath, utf-8

**Scenario**

I am getting content from a website uing PHP, DOMDOCUMENT and XPATH. My code makes sure the HTML content is UTF-8 and tries to remove certain nodes that match a query.

**Part of code where the issue lies**

Inside a PHP class:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$this->dom=new DOMDocument("4.01", "utf-8");
$xpath=new DOMXPath($this->dom);
$this->motorConfig['xPath_N']="//div[@class='pdfprnt-bottom-right']/following-sibling::*";
$content_text_dirty='
... aleba</p><div class="pdfprnt-bottom-right">Y entonces...</div><div><p> ...
';

if($this->motorConfig['xPath_N']){
$content_text_dirty=str_replace("\0", '', $content_text_dirty); //Avoid PHP BUG http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925533/php-dom-loadhtml-method-unusual-warning
$this->dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content_text_dirty, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath=new DOMXPath($this->dom); //her cuz must be set after loading HTML into DOM
$nodes_to_remove=$xpath->query($this->motorConfig['xPath_N']);
var_dump($nodes_to_remove); --> bool(false)
...
```

**Question**:

What is a good way to know WHY xpath query is not finding the results?

**Extra notes**

As a curiosity, PHP is not showing any result for any query when I remove the part:

```
str_replace("\0", '', $content_text_dirty);
```

I have been using this PHP class for a long while, to scrape data from different websites. But this only happens sometimes, in some specific websites. The current case regards [this site](http://ecocosas.com/eg/fotografo-hace-arte-con-la-basura-encontrada-en-la-mayor-area-natural-de-mexico/). [Actually, trying the same xpath query with FirePath returns the match]

Comment: as a starter, just look at the XML (it is not shown here) and the XPath. the PHP code does not matter. then use any tool (online or local) for interactively running XPath expressions against XML, and that will let you experiment with the expression very easily.

Comment: you are setting `$this->motorConfig['xPath_N']` to an xpath string but then executing an xpath query using a different string `$nodes_to_remove=$xpath->query($this->motorConfig['xPath_MAKIFLAKI']);` is that intentional?

Comment: @KeithHall Ups, sorry for the mistake. I actually renamed MAKIFLAKI to N when posting the question so it would be easier to read. (I fixed the mistake in my question too.) - Thanks.

Comment: @dret Thank you :) I tried it with a firefox extension and it works fine, so the problem is not in the query string itself. I mentioned the source at the bottom of my question. I guess it's some kind of misscodification issue in the DOM. Will keep researching and posting infos here.